# C# y Windows Form ¿Cómo evitar que la creacion de un nuevo form atrape el foco?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, focus

Básicamente he creado una aplicación que llama a otra repetidas veces mediante la siguiente función:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("OtraAplicacion.exe");
psi.Arguments = ean;
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

Esa otra aplicación es también un windows form y quiero que se ejecute de fondo mientras haces otras cosas cómodamente.
El problema es que básicamente cuando se crea se me lleva el foco y si estas escribiendo en un word por ejemplo te deja de escribir...

¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutarla en segundo plano o algo así? o ¿Le puedo cambiar las propiedades al form para que no me atrape el focus al empezar?

Comment: Mira a ver si [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31628640/579895) te ayuda

Comment: @Pikoh ¡Gracias por responder! Pero no soluciona mi problema :(
Explican como hacer que se ejecute la ventana minimizada o oculta, pero se sigue llevando el foco de lo que estoy haciendo cuando esta se abre

Comment: Has probado añadiendo `p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`? Si no hay ventana..no deberia llevarse el foco

Comment: @Pikoh Nope, no funciona, y he probado ya un monton de formas de ocultar la ventana, pero parece que al ejecutar una da por hecho que vas a trabajar con ella o algo y te mueve el foco, voy a hacer unos cuantas pruebas mas a ver si puedo evitarlo de algun modo :/